# Вытащить из фразы текст, находящийся между определёнными словами

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, допустим:

```
Съешь же ещё этих мягких |Какая-то фраза| французских булок, да выпей чаю
```

Как при помощи JS вытащить `|Какая-то фраза|`, зная только то, что он будет находиться между **мягких** и **французских**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно воспользоваться методом [String.prototype.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

```js
var str = "Съешь же ещё этих мягких |Какая-то фраза| французских булок, да выпей чаю";
var regExp = /мягких\s+(.*)\s+французских/;
var result = str.match(regExp)[1];
console.log(result);
```

Или методом [RegExp.prototype.exec](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec):

```js
var str = "Съешь же ещё этих мягких |Какая-то фраза| французских булок, да выпей чаю";
var regExp = /мягких\s+(.*)\s+французских/;
var result = regExp.exec(str)[1];
console.log(result);
```